# SQL find average of time difference between two rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, presto

I have a use case which am trying to solve using sql query.

Query Engine is based on Presto 0.172, https://prestodb.io/

Lets say I have a data like this

```
+----------+------------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
| location | actiontype | actionstate | uuid |     lastupdatedtime      |
+----------+------------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
| x        | type1      | start       |  123 | 2018-09-09T16:54:37.648Z |
| x        | type1      | start       |  123 | 2018-09-09T16:55:37.648Z |
| x        | type1      | start       |  123 | 2018-09-09T16:56:37.648Z |
| x        | type1      | end         |  123 | 2018-09-09T16:57:37.648Z |
| x        | type1      | end         |  123 | 2018-09-09T16:58:37.648Z |
| y        | type1      | start       |  567 | 2018-09-09T14:57:37.648Z |
| y        | type1      | end         |  567 | 2018-09-09T14:58:37.648Z |
+----------+------------+-------------+------+--------------------------+
```

I am trying to find avg time difference when a particular actiontype lets say type1 starts and end for a given uuid

i.e. group by UUID, actiontype and location

In some cases I can have multiple entries for same actiontype and actionstate and in that case I need to pic the MAX(lastupdatedtime)

something like

```
select AVG(date_diff( MAX(lastupdatedtime of start)) and MAX(lastupdatedtime of end)
```

in table datatable
group by location, actiontype, uuid.

Comment: please tag the database being used.

Comment: Updated the query engine

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation in subtraction.

```
select TIMEDIFF(MAX(case when actionstate='end' then lastupdatedtime end)
               ,MAX(case when actionstate='start' then lastupdatedtime end)
               )
from datatable 
where actionstate in ('start','end')
group by location, actiontype, uuid
having count(distinct actionstate) = 2
```

`avg` isn't needed as there is only one result for a combination of group by columns.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi,
I was able to do minor changes to above to get what I wanted

had to use date_diff in prestodb query format instead of TIMEDIFF

The only issue is that the above query is also picking up rows where start/end does not exit and picking MAX values as empty/null.
is there a way to ignore the tuples where actionstate does not matches either start/end or both.

Comment: @Scorpion .. check the edit which ensures there should be `start` and `end` rows for a grouping combination.

Comment: I tried this but its looks like this is not a valid query, Getting exception from AWS Athena as
Error Code: InvalidRequestException;
as soon as am adding line having count(distinct actionstate) =2